# Margin Space on Selected Tabbar in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

I am working on a tab bar controller & I have different tab bar elements. Everything works fine but during testing, I found side a small margin on the selected tab as you can see in red circle in image:

[image]

[image]
I have already set

```
 tabBarController.tabBar.itemPositioning = UITabBarItemPositioningFill;
```

Can any one suggest, what am I doing wrong?

Any idea would be great.

Comment: Are you sure the image itself is OK?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set imageInsets of the tabBarItem.

Comment: I have done that. please suggest if you want to specify any component in imageInsets

Comment: [tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@“abc”] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"abc"]];

tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, -2, 0);